# Can I host DNSChef on my google cloud compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google

I was wondering if it is against the terms of service, etc. to host the application DNSChef on the compute engine as I do not want to violate TOS or rules and get my account flagged as it is used for business.

Thank you!

Comment: DNSChef is a highly configurable DNS proxy for Penetration Testers and Malware Analysts. I'd assume since penetration testing itself isn't illegal, it is all rather about what you are planning to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing and hosting said software will not break the TOS. Nevertheless, as you can see in this FAQ [1] in order to perform Penetration testing you need to ensure that said test don't break  the TOS [2] or the Cloud Platform Acceptable Use Policy [3] and limit them to your projects.

Have a nice day!

---

[1] - https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6262505?hl=en#penetration-tests
[2] - https://cloud.google.com/terms/
[3] - https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup